# How to apply self in method parameter in Python

Tags: python

Actually , I want to write

```
def w_cell(self, r, c, val, style=XLS.get_cell_stlye(self))
```

But it cannot, and show me the error

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

How could I set the default style in parameter rather than in function.

Thanks

```
class XLS():

    def get_cell_stlye(self):        
        return xlwt.easyxf("alignment: horizontal center,\
         vertical center, wrap true ;")


class TestCGI(object, XLS):
    def w_cell(self, r, c, val, style='null'):
            if style == 'null':
                style=XLS.get_cell_stlye(self)
            self.sht.write(r, c, val, style)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it in the function itself is fine, although you probably want to do it like this:

```
class TestCGI(object, XLS):
    def w_cell(self, r, c, val, style=None):
        if style is not None:
            style=XLS.get_cell_stlye(self)
        self.sht.write(r, c, val, style)
```

Comment: In this case, I would is `if style is not None` -- Your version would also pick up `style=0` which may or may not be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't write that.  Default arguments are evaluated *when the function is created*.  At the function creation time, `self` doesn't exist yet<sup>1</sup>, so it can't have anything to do with the calculation of the default value.

<sup><sup>1</sup>after all, if the *class* doesn't exist yet, it can't have any instances -- and even if it did, which instance would it pick to be `self`?</sup>